# React fetch JSON data inside loop

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch, state, use-effect

I need to render a list of buttons, in which I have the value coming from one JSON (an url to an object in a server, stored in a local file), and the displayed text from another JSON (the title of the object, which I can only get through a fetch function).

My local JSON looks like this. From it, I need to get the category name and the list of URLS and use them to make a category button (with the value being the list of URLS and the displayed text being the name).

```
{
  "layerUrls": [
    {"name": "Education",
      "urls": [
    "someurl1",
    "someurl2"
    ]},
    {"name": "Transports",
      "urls": [
    "someurl3",
    "someurl4"
    ]
  }]
}
```

Then, I need to get each URL in a button (in the div that matches its category), and I need to get the title of the object linked to each URL from the server. To do all of this, I'm looping through **layerUrls** to get each category and create the category button. Then, in each loop, I'm mapping the list of URLs to a series of buttons and fetching the names in the server.

```
generateButtons = (css) => {
    // Styling
    const style = css
    // Get local JSON data
    const data = this.props.config.layerUrls
    // Init lists
    const list = []
    const solo = []
    // Looping to create a div per category with 1 category button & multiple individual buttons
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let donneesCateg = data[i]
      let listURLS = donneesCateg["urls"]


      list.push(<div>
        {/* Create category buttons */}
        <button id={donneesCateg["name"]} className="categ" value={listURLS} onClick={this.selectChangeMultiple}>{donneesCateg["name"]}</button>
        {/* Map individual buttons */}
        {listURLS.map((item) => {
          const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
            url: item
          });

          fetch(item + "?f=pjson")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              const titre = (data.name).replaceAll('_', ' ').substring(1).toLowerCase()
              solo.push(<button id={donneesCateg["name"]} className="btn" value={item} onClick={this.selectChangeSingle}>{titre}</button>)
            })
          return solo
        })
        }
      </div>)

    }
    // Return the buttons
    return (
      <div>
        <style>
          {style}
        </style>
        {list}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The trouble comes from the **fetch** function I'm using to retrieve the name from the server for each object. I'm pushing the buttons to a list and returning it... Except that it doesn't return anything. I only get the category buttons and that's it. I tried with **useEffect** with no more success, and I tried to push the name only to the list, but I got an infinite loop.

Can anyone help ? Thanks!

Comment: don't... do that. collect and transform your data outside of the render.

Comment: @KevinB I agree that I should be doing that, but I can't see how. I need the URLs from the `map` function in `listURLS` to fetch the data. And I need to stay in the loop so that the buttons are created in the right div. Can you point out to a solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*fetch* is an [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) function, i.e the rest of the code doesn't wait for it to finish executing unless explicitly instructed to do so. Instead of:

```
fetch(item + "?f=pjson")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          const titre = (data.name).replaceAll('_', ' ').substring(1).toLowerCase()
          solo.push(<button id={donneesCateg["name"]} className="btn" value={item} onClick={this.selectChangeSingle}>{titre}</button>)
        })
return solo
```

use:

```
const data = await fetch(item + "?f=pjson")
    .then(res => res.json())

const titre = (data.name).replaceAll('_', ' ').substring(1).toLowerCase()
solo.push(<button id={donneesCateg["name"]} className="btn" value={item} onClick={this.selectChangeSingle}>{titre}</button>)
  
return solo
```

also, be sure to declare the function as async at the top:

```
generateButtons = async css => { //...
```